# Google search sniffer global conf is not defined

Tags: python, scapy

I have made a google search sniffer with the help of the book Violent Python but when i run this code using `python sniffer.py -i mon0` it says

```
  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py, line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 23, in main 
    conmf.iface = options.interface
  NameError: global name 'conf' is not defined
```

I am using the latest version of scapy on windows with python 2.7. Oh, and i also kind of bodge installed it by moving the folders into the right place.

```
from scapy import *
import optparse

def findGoogle(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        payload = pkt .getLayer(Raw).load
        if 'GET' in payload:
            if 'google' in payload:
                r = re.findall(r'(?!)\&q=(.*?)\&', payload)
                if r:
                    search = r[0].split('&')[0]
                    search = search.replace('q=', '').replace('+', ' ').replace('%20', ' ')
                    print "Searched for" + search

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog -i '+ '<interface>')
    parser.add_option('-i', dest='interface', type='string', help='specify interface to listen on')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.interface == None:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    else:
        conf.iface = options.interface
    try:
        print '[*]Starting Google Sniffer.'
        sniff(filter='tcp port 80', prn=findGoogle)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You didn't claim a variable called conf in main function.

Comment: You never define or use `conf` other than in that else statement. Something's missing, or `conf.iface` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mistyped a line [while transcribing it](https://github.com/reconSF/python/blob/master/violent_python/sniff/google-searches.py),

```
from scapy import *
```

should read

```
from scapy.all import *
```

The `scapy` documentation is somewhat sparse, but evidently `conf` is defined in there.

EDIT: Digging into the source, it looks like `all.py` imports [`config.py`](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/src/17cfed75e2249520bb1772be9dfacda930c01f20/scapy/config.py?at=default), which includes the line

```
conf=Conf()
```

so that's definitely the culprit.

Comment: when I put from scapy.all import * it says a really long message then no module named pcapy

Comment: @QwertyFish Are you sure that you've installed `scapy`?

Comment: well... Yes and no. When I installed it using the proper method it (going into cmd into the scapy folder and typing python setup.py install) it came up with an error so I copied a folder instead. I probably need to properly install it

Comment: @QwertyFish Yes, that's not going to work. The best way is to install [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) and then to use `pip` to install `scapy`. Also, please upvote/accept this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Doing python setup.py install worked this time. I am very confused

Comment: but, one thing I don't understand is it says no module named pycapy edit: I might just install python 2.6 as it seems it is easier to work with scapy with it

Comment: @QwertyFish Did you import `scapy` or `pycapy`, or `pcapy`?

Comment: I tried from scapy.all import * as the source code does but it says a long error then it says a long list of errors and it says no module named pcapy and if I try import pycapy or import pcapy it says no module named pycapy or pcapy. How can I install pycapy?

Comment: It's not `pcapy`, it's `scapy`. You've posted `pcapy` four times here. It looks like you have a typo.

Comment: I know but it says no module named pycapy when I do from scapy.all import * . So pycapy must me missing

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. It sounds like something went wrong installing `scapy`. I would strongly recommend deleting it and reinstalling it via `pip`.